# React Native AsyncStorage stops working once app is offline

Tags: android, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I have a relatively simple app (my first) that needs to display information that is retrieved from a GraphQL query and then stored in AsyncStorage. Everything works fine until you turnoff data/Wifi connections and relaunch the app -  it will not load the same local data it did when networking is on. This is the same on a physical or emulated Android device.

There are no data calls except when the user initially sets their details. The app is built with version 2.7.1 of Expo & AWS Amplify. I have wasted several days with this final issue and gotten the same behaviour with Expo SecureStore & Amplify Cache and am loath to go down the route of learning and including Redux on such a simple app...

```
//import from react native not react
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

//calling a function as app loads
componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState();
}

//retrieving String from AsyncStorage
_loadInitialState = async () => {
    try {
        const policyNum = await AsyncStorage.getItem('policyNum')
        //...
    } catch {
        //...
    }

//setting state
if (policyNum != null && policyNum != undefined) {
        this.setState({ policyNum: policyNum })
    //...
}

//the original setting of the item
setPolicyDetails = async () => {
    if (this.state.policyNum != null) {
        const policyNumber = this.state.policyNum
        this.state.policyNumSet = true
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('policyNum', policyNumber)
        } catch (err) { 
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re clearly mutuating state with the line `this.state.policyNumSet = true` you should be using `this.setState({policyNumSet:true})` instead.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I thought I updated all of those early noob mistakes...  I'll double-check for more leftovers and give that a go.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to be the issue

Comment: I didn't think it would be the issue. It was just a coding mistake that I was pointing out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you storing a string?  asyncstorage only can store strings . try using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

```
_loadInitialState = async () => {
    try {
        var policyNum = await AsyncStorage.getItem('policyNum')
        policyNum = JSON.parse(policyNum) // converting to original
        //...
    } catch {
        //...
    }

//setting state
if (policyNum != null && policyNum != undefined) {
        this.setState({ policyNum: policyNum })
    //...
}

//the original setting of the item
setPolicyDetails = async () => {
    if (this.state.policyNum != null) {
        const policyNumber = this.state.policyNum
        this.setState({ policyNumSet: true })
        try {
            var policyNumberString = JSON.stringify(policyNumber)
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('policyNum', policyNumberString) //converting to string
        } catch (err) { 
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ValdaXD - Thanks, yes this is a string & I have been stringifying a GraphQL query result as JSON and retrieving them successfully & displaying them on relaunch. It only fails to retrieve anything when networking is disabled

Comment: That's really, really strange , since asyncstorage should work offline. Try the other solution , if that doen't work delete every api/fetch call on start and start  the app online, if the data loads, it's a bug, if the data doesn't load it means it never was there and you should console.log the policyNum   you are retrieving

Comment: It is weird, but I've come across several bug reports about AsyncStorage not working, but not that it works with a connection and not when offline.

The app only makes an API request on a user interaction (they submit their code). When the app loads up it only checks for the AsyncStorage and then sets the states for displaying the information on the homescreen. If they choose to update their code a new request is sent & saved

Comment: Thanks ValaXD! I had another look and there is an api checking for user information that does not work offline on from a token as I first thought, but polls a service.

Answer (score 0):

You are using badly the fact of change the state.

Where you do this:

```
    this.state.policyNumSet = true
```

You should change the state with the setState() function like this:

```
    this.setState({ policyNumSet: true })
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a leftover from when I started learning React Native from a poor Youtube video. I realised the mistake in this and updated all of state changes except this one. I'm hoping this is it...

Comment: Make me know if it isn't

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

This was a conflict with an external API